# How can I hide emacs status line?

Tags: emacs

I would like to hide completely the emacs status line. Is that possible?  I could not find anything about this through Google.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On a more lispy level, setting mode-line-format to nil will remove it. See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Top.html)

Comment: I dig a little about mode-line-format, http://webonastick.com/emacs-lisp/hide-mode-line.el, but not yet able to hide it :)

Comment: Just go to the *scratch* buffer and enter: `(setq mode-line-format nil)` and press `C-j`.

Comment: I just read your response. That is very nice. But, can we make that to affect all buffer? I just realized that it's only affect scratch buffer itself

Comment: Evaluating `(setq mode-line-format nil)` is buffer-specific, meaning that it only affects the buffer in which it's executed. If you want it globally you evaluate `(setq-default mode-line-format nil)`, if you want it in a specific buffer you hit `M-: (setq mode-line-format nil)` in said buffer.

Answer (score 9):

#### Hide status line globally

```lisp
(setq-default mode-line-format nil)
```

The preferred way to completely hide the status line is `(setq-default mode-line-format nil)` in your init.el file.

---

#### Hide status line of the current buffer

```lisp
(setq mode-line-format nil)
```

Hide status line of the current buffer by typing `M-:` followed by `(setq mode-line-format nil)` when prompted.

Answer (score 6):

[Emacs darkroom](http://www.martyn.se/code/emacs/darkroom-mode/) might be what you're looking for. It will take away all possible distractions of Emacs' interface.

---

Original site seems to be down *(as of Jan 2014)*.  Here is the source on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/phromo/darkroom-mode/overview/)

Comment: thanks, it close to what I expect, and it did hide the status line. perfect! I just need tweak a little to get it to what I need

Comment: Back up. *(as of April 2014)*

Comment: Both links seem to be gone as of this moment, but there's [a copy of the repo on GitHub](https://github.com/joaotavora/darkroom) at least.